# Router Outlet in sibling component

Tags: angular, typescript

**What is my problem:**
I want to create a similar web shop like this one:
https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/tag/foto-video-520

I have my side nav on the left side in one component and in the center of the page I want to have a custom component. The custom component can be either a list with all articles from one category or one article with specific data about the article. The goal is, that the side nav should always stay there. So basically I don't want to refresh to site and only update the custom component.

So basically my idea is, that I need to have a router-outlet tag in my custom component and somehow tell the custom component from my side nav component which routes to take if a category gets clicked in the side nav. But it could also be possible that I need to tell in the custom component itself what route to take if a single article gets clicked. But I can't think about a possible solution.

Can someone tell me if that is the right approach or if I should not use a router-outlet in this scenario?

Comment: Using a named `router-outlet` is a fine idea, in fact many apps use it for use cases very similar to yours. Here are two good articles to get you started if need be: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/ http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Narm I saw your post in the other question, but I wasn't sure if this was the thing I was searching for :D.